# AWS CloudFormation UserData en Launch Template

Tags: aws, cloud, amazon, amazon-web-services

Buenas compañeros de internete.
Estoy trabajando en un Cloudformation: La idea es crear un `AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate`
En la parte de `LaunchTemplateData` me deja meter un chorro de bash y lo ejecuta.

---

Por otra parte, en la zona e instancias existe esto: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html

---

Sería posible utilizar `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` en un `UserData` definido en un `LaunchTemplateData`

Muchas gracias de antebrazo y un saludo.

Comment: Hasta donde vi por ahora, solo se puede incluír en un 'LaunchConfiguration' =>
'AWS::CloudFormation::Init' Pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo en un LaunchTemplate.

Comment: Se pueden ver ejemplos en: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-appframeworks-us-west-2.html